# How can I create thumbnails for video with wand?

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I want to create thumbnails for video with wand
and I try to run commands below:

```
>>> from wand.image import Image
>>> vid = Image(filename='example.mp4')
```

but I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/leiz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 2534, in __init__
    self.read(filename=filename, resolution=resolution)
  File "/home/leiz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 2601, in read
    self.raise_exception()
  File "/home/leiz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/resource.py", line 222, in raise_exception
    raise e
wand.exceptions.BlobError: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-24346h472NGIWl2wR.pam': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709
```

I'm sure that file 'example.mp4' exists and it puzzle me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install the [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) application. ImageMagick passes `.mp4` files to delegate by calling the following

```
"ffmpeg" -nostdin -v -1 -i "%i" -vframes %S -vcodec pam -an -f rawvideo -y "%u.pam" 2> "%Z"
```

So if `ffmpeg` is not installed, then the unique intermediate file doesn't exists, and you'll see message

> ```
> unable to open image [PATH]: No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709
> ```

or even

> ```
> delegate failed [COMMAND] @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1332.
> ```